# How to convert list of tuples to django queryset?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am using cursor.execute to run a raw sql query. The return type is a list of tuples. This throws Attribute error. Is there a way to convert this to or receive as  a queryset??

Answer (score 0):

You should select pk list:

```
queryset =  model.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list)
```

It is important that it won't keep the original ordering.

Comment: The SQL query returns records from a main table and has annotated values from other tables as well.